# Google Tag Manager not tracking clicks in preview mode

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I am trying to set up Google Tag Manager When in preview mode, `click` events are not being registered in the Summary box at the bottom left.

Its working fine on other sites and I can't think of anything that I have missed in the setup. Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Check if the Click variables are enabled in the section for built-in variables.

Answer (score -1):

As mentioned by [Eike Pierstorff](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47334058/google-tag-manager-not-tracking-clicks-in-preview-mode?noredirect=1#comment81620380_47334058)

> Check if the Click variables are enabled in the section for built-in variables